# What causes a thorn like feeling when your put your hand in water in electronic appliances?

Tags: current, electricity, shock, appliances

I live in India, the voltage supply in houses is 220V.

Sometimes, for example in my washing machine, when it is full of water and I put my hand in it, I get a feeling like a thorn/tiny nail is piercing my finger near nails. Same happens if some liquid is touch inside freezer.

Sometimes it happens when I even touch the body of fridge.

It doesn't give a shock, but I'm serious about it. Is it a low level of shock or is it something else?

It happens when the appliances are plugged in.

Comment: Bad earthing is quite often the problem.

Comment: My washing machine has two pin plug. Is it the cause?

Comment: Probably the cause.

Comment: What about the plug on the fridge and freezer?

Comment: @HandyHowie it has 3 pin plug.

Comment: You will understand why if you watch this https://youtu.be/wD5gv1A9-9Q

Comment: any motor will have electric-field coupling from the windings to the armature (rotor) or the casing. Assume 3cm by 3cm region, with 1mm insulation thickness. Assume air (Eo=1) as dielectric. you'll have about 10pF coupling. Then use I = C * dV/dT to compute the maximum current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vikas, you didn't state your country or the voltage at the plug so I don't know if your washer is 240V or 230V or 120V but since you notice the problem with your fridge also (and it's not static discharge), then it seems to be a condition of your house wiring.  Because your plug is 2 wire, you have no earth wire (also known as ground and protective earth).  It seems to be leakage current from the appliance to the metal enclosure and your body becomes a path of this leakage when you touch it.  The purpose of the earth wire is to provide a return path for leakage currents or in the event of a short to the metal enclosure.  If your home does not have 3 wire receptacles then you will need an electrician to wire them in.

Comment: Edited. Kindly check.

Comment: If possible have an electrician convert the washer to 3 pin with the earth tied to the metal enclosure.  It may also indicate a failure developing with your washer.

Comment: one more thing. Why don't we get a strong/proper shock because of this? Why a only a small feeling?

Answer (score 1):

Its electricity flowing through your hand via the water and affecting your nervous system.

In the shower in my gf's parents house I would often get a tingling from touching the faucet. I was sure they didn't want me dating their daughter! It turned out a wire was touching the metal drop ceiling support above the shower  and the metal support had somehow touched a drain somewhere, thus completing me in the circuit. The tub was enamel coated cast iron.

Comment: Okay, but doubt is, why I'm not getting (may we never get one) a strong shock? Why only a needle on finger like feeling?